# Spring MVC Get POST body before controllers

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, post

I need to read POST requests body without consuming it.

I've tried it in a several ways in my custom HandlerInterceptor and nothing works. All I've tried to do to wrap and cache request bodies, at a some point, didn't work, probably even because I cannot control what Spring does.

So I thinked another thing: at some point Spring will try to map request body to an object and pass it to the right Controller. I can intercept this action and get that object before the Controller is called?

Comment: Why do you need to read the body before request processing? What do you need to do with it? You can only proces a request once and hence it will not work without duplicating the reading (like in the logging filters of Spring for example).

Comment: Because I prefer to log every request in a single point instead insert a log into every method in every controller.

Comment: For that Spring already has special filters, use those instead of rolling your own. There are also other existing solutions for that. All boil down to storing the response in-memory and implement the reading in a request wrapper.

Comment: I've tried one of these filter but I can't control and I have to log other things. Get the possibility to intercept request is useful even if I have to perform other controls.

Comment: As stated take a look a the spring logging filters and use the same approach. You simply cannot read a request twice and you have to create a specialized request wrapper for that.

Comment: Well, to be honest if I set the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter with setIncludePayload(true) it doesn't log POST body...

Comment: Did you enable debug logging for the filter? Else it won't log anything.

Comment: Yep: the filter is logging. Simply doesn't log the payload.

Comment: It will only log the payload that is getting processed. I fyou aren't binding/processing the payload it won't log.

Comment: Hmm, I've found the point: I need to increase the MaxPayloadLenght. Now I can log the body. Thanks for your help, I'll write a post with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: using a CommonsRequestLoggingFilter Spring can log even the payload of the requests. The only bother I'm finding is that I can read the payload only in afterRequest method because in the beforeRequest is absent.

More info on CommonsRequestLoggingFilter [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging).

Answer (score 0):

Once the request body is read from the request before reaching controller you can not use anywhere. So what you can do is to read the body from `HttpServletRequest` in the `Filter` implementation and set it in `ThreadLocal` variable. Then you can read from that `ThreadLocal`. Below is the sample code.

Inside `Filter` implementation class

```
try {
    YourModel yourModel = // Read the request body

    RequestContextHolder.setContext(yourModel);
}finally {
    RequestContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

and at any point of time in the current request you can do like below.

```
RequestContextHolder.getContext();
```

Here is the `RequestContextHolder` class

```
public class RequestContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<YourModel> THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setContext(YourModel yourModel) {
        THREAD_LOCAL.set(yourModel);
    }

    public static YourModel getContext() {
       return THREAD_LOCAL.get();
    }

    public static void clearContext() {
       THREAD_LOCAL.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understand: where, in my filter, I can get the request body?

Comment: from `HttpServletRequest` you can parse the body to your model class. Anyway you got the solution.

Comment: Ok, but in which filter method? And if I parse the request body I'll consume it.

Comment: inside `doFilter()` method and of course, yes, you'll consume it. But that is set in `ThreadLocal` so that it is accessible from anywhere in current request.

Comment: In this way Spring cannot read the request body, so every request will fail.